# html additional information icon/button

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, popup

So I want to add another feature to my website. It is about key figures. and some of them should be explained in more detail. I want to make it as a small information icon next to the word, which should be explained. When u hover over this information icon(or click), a small pop up should appear with all the needed information to understand the meaning of this key figure. Similar to the following picture [pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6hIt.png)

I don't know how to search for such a tutorial or how to completely program it. Does anyone know a good video/blog/how to search for sth like this or has some code?
Thank you very much,
Best Regards,
Julian

Comment: Hi, try searching for popup or tooltip+ CSS to get going, have a go at creating your code and if you get stuck show your code in your question so we can help you see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*how to search for such a tutorial or how to completely program it.*

What you described is often called **tooltip**, so if you want to implement it using javascript search for *javascript tooltip tutorial* or similar.

If you want to keep it simple you might harness HTML [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) attribute, for example

```
<span title="explanation">?</span>
```

will result in `?` which when mouse hover over will show box with `explanation` inside.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic example I can give is with CSS :hover selector:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        .info{
            display: none;
        }
        .icon:hover ~ .info{
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>YourText.</p><div class="icon">!</div>
    <div class="info">Your information.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

In this code, whenever the mouse moves over the "!", the information class is displayed, you can obviously switch out the "!" for a better looking icon (I would suggest trying one of the https://fontawesome.com/ packages) but the basic idea is here.

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer!

Comment: @julianff1 You're very welcome!, feel free to mark it as accepted if it works for you :)